# Will the cookies be shared across multiple subdomains, if all subdomains point to the same single website?

Tags: javascript, web, cookies, subdomain

I would like to create website, which can behave differently based on subdomains.

If I set a certain cookie on subdomain A, can I read/access it on subdomain C?
Or the cookie binds to the subdomain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you read this question [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain), in summary it says that what's important is the domain parameter you define to set the cookie. What your looking for is something like this ".mydomain.com".

Comment: Thank you, the linked post really helped!

Answer (score 2):

When you set cookie, there is a `Domain` attribute. This is its explanation from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

> **Domain attribute** The Domain attribute specifies which hosts can
> receive a cookie. If unspecified, the attribute defaults to the same
> host that set the cookie, excluding subdomains. If Domain is
> specified, then subdomains are always included. Therefore, specifying
> Domain is less restrictive than omitting it. However, it can be
> helpful when subdomains need to share information about a user.
>
> For example, if you set Domain=mozilla.org, cookies are available on
> subdomains like developer.mozilla.org.

Basically, you just need to specify the `Domain` attribute in `Set-Cookie`.